# Adicionar resultados de TextBox's de uma pagina numa tabela de outra página HTML

Tags: javascript, html, table

Eu tenho uma pagina HTML com uma tabela vazia e quando carrego num botão , direcciona-me para outra pagina onde tem 5 inputs , o que pretendo fazer em javascript é colocar o resultado desses 5 inputs na tabela da pagina anterior.

Pagina 1, nome = Calendario.html:

```
    ....

        <table id="myTable2">
          <thead>
              <tr>
            <th>Disciplina</th>
            <th>Método de avaliação</th>
            <th>Data da avaliação</th>
            <th>Antecedência</th>
            <th>Duração por dia</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>

<a href="CriarPlanoDeEstudo.html"><button type="button">Criar plano de estudo</button></a><br>


        .....
```

Pagina 2 , nome=CriarPlanoDeEstudo.html

```
Antecedência: <input type="text" name="nome" id="antecedencia" placeholder="Dias de antecedencia"><br><p></p>

Data do Método: <input type="date" id="datadometodo" ><br><p></p>

Disciplina: <div id="disciplina"> </div> 

Duração por dia: <input type="text" name="nome" id="duracaopordia" placeholder="Duração em horas">   <br><p></p>

Método de avaliação: <input type="text" name="nome" id="metododeavaliaçao" placeholder="Nome do método">  <br><p></p>


<a href="Calendario.html"><button type="button" id="concluir" >Concluir</button></a>
```

Comment: Mas porque você precisa ir para outra página para preencher os dados? Você pode deixar na mesma página que adicionar os valores na tabela quando o usuário clicar no botão Concluir.

Comment: Eu estou a fazer isto para design de páginas e o que pretendo é mesmo ter a tablea noutra pagina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode deixar na mesma página que adicionar os valores na tabela quando o usuário clicar no botão Concluir. Exemplo bem simples:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $table = $("#myTable2 tbody");

  $('#concluir').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   var antecedencia = $('#antecedencia').val(),
    datadometodo = $('#datadometodo').val(),
    disciplina = $('#disciplina').val(),
    duracaopordia = $('#duracaopordia').val(),
    metododeavaliacao = $('#metododeavaliacao').val(),
    linha = "<tr>";

   if (disciplina == "") {
    alert("Preencha o campo disciplina");
    return false;
   }
          
            datadometodo = datadometodo.split('-').reverse().join('/');

   linha += "<td>" + disciplina + "</td>";
   linha += "<td>" + metododeavaliacao + "</td>";
   linha += "<td>" + datadometodo + "</td>";
   linha += "<td>"+antecedencia+"</td>";
   linha += "<td>" + duracaopordia + "</td>";
   linha += "</tr>";
   $table.append(linha);
  });
 });
```

```html
<form id="formulario">

 <p>
  <label for="antecedencia">Antecedência: </label>
  <input type="text" id="antecedencia" placeholder="Dias de antecedencia">
 </p>

 <p>
  <label for="datadometodo">Data do Método: </label>
  <input type="date" id="datadometodo" >
 </p>

 <p>
  <label for="disciplina">Disciplina:</label>
  <input type="text" id="disciplina">
 </p>

 <p>
  <label for="duracaopordia">Duração por dia:</label>
  <input type="text" id="duracaopordia" placeholder="Duração em horas">
 </p>
 <p>
  <label for="">Método de avaliação:</label>
  <input type="text" id="metododeavaliacao" placeholder="Nome do método">
 </p>

 <button type="button" id="concluir" >Concluir</button>

</form>

 <table id="myTable2">
          <thead>
              <tr>
            <th>Disciplina</th>
            <th>Método de avaliação</th>
            <th>Data da avaliação</th>
            <th>Antecedência</th>
            <th>Duração por dia</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sim  mas o que pretendo é mesmo especifico , que é ter a tabela noutra pagina diferente dos inputs

Comment: Certo, então acredito que você possa salvar as informações usando `localStorage`

Comment: Sim , mas ja tentei e nao consegui

Comment: E usando cookie?